# (De)Serializing multiple items to file

Tags: c#, serialization, persistence

I want to serialize/deserialize multiple object from/to a file. The syntax should be similar to this:

```
obj.Append(byteArray);
obj.Append(byteArray);
obj.Append(byteArray);
IEnumerable<byte[]> obj.Extract();
```

While this is very simple to accomplish (e.g., write a class that uses a filestream and protobuf-net internally), I'm wondering if there is any more elegant way of doing this. Is there any class (from a third party library), that uses a serializer to write to an filestream?

**Edit:** I need this as a filestream that captures video data that is sent through network. So the filestream must be open for a dedicated amount of time. My previous solution was to save every video frame to a new file, but it's not scalable (especially for hdd, and increasing video partners).

Comment: A filestream is not a network stream.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
using(var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
      var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      formatter.Serialize(stream, firstObjectToSerialize);
      formatter.Serialize(stream, secondObjectToSerialize);
}
```

Comment: So, don't put stream in a using statement (make it a memory variable) and don't make stream a FileStream (make it a NetworkStream or something applicable).  If you don't want a BinaryFormatter you some other type of formatter, like TextFormatter or SoeapFormatter.